# Problem with Shadow or Elevation in React-Native

Tags: styles, react-native, shadow

I have a problem with adding shadow to my View Component.
here is the style object:

```
header: {
        width: '95%',
        height: '15%',
        marginTop: 50,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderRadius: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        elevation: 2,
    },
```

and it looks like this :
[image]

and as soon as I add these style properties :

```
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: 'white',
```

it looks better but not the best way:
[image]

what is my problem? can you help me ?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Could you show a picture of the shadow you wish to emulate?

Comment: Additionally could you supply us with the rest of the components code. This would give us more insight into what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Try giving `backgroundColor: "white"` property to the `View` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BackgroundColor:white fixed the problem, thanks to @Ajay

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to add a shadow to a `<View/>` component I would suggest you to use the [shadow props](https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props). You can add a shadow to a view component by using the style properties like so:

```
// Just picked some random values for each of the properties.

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 20,
      height: 10
     },
     shadowOpacity: 0.2,
     shadowRadius: 20
  },
});
```

### Result of example code

[image]

I am not able to replicate the styling you have shown with just the code you have supplied. So I can't give you an answer as to why adding `borderWidth` and `borderColor` properties change your shadows. If you'd like me to dive into that, please supply the code of the entire component or even better an [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev).

What I did notice is that you used the `elevation` style property, which is will only add a shadow on Android ([source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#elevation-android)). Additionally this property will also affect the z-order for overlapping views, so I would advise against using this if it is just for shadows.

[Expo Snack Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@fluous/310117)

Comment: Well . The problem was i forgot to add backgroundColor. That fixed the problem. Thanks to @Ajay.  The shadow*: styles are for iPhone only. And since im programming Android Application the Elevation was enough . 

Answer (score 0):

use backgroundColor:'white' fixed the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).